# Syntax Error access violation in query Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am having trouble in finding and understanding my mistake. I have table payments and i want to show this data on my students page, (by getting student_id). It should get the data by student_id.

```
payments{id, student_id, course_id, transfer_amount, payment_type_id, is_paid, date}
```

But this mistake keeps showing. Where is my mistake, guys please help.Any help is appreciated.
Here is **StudentsController.php**

```
public function payments($id, Request $request) {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
        $payment = Payment::where('student_id', $id)-> get();
        $student->has('payments')->where('student_id', $request->id)->get();
        return view('students.groups', compact('student', 'payment'));

    }
```

Here is my model **Student.php**

```
public function payments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment','payments', 'student_id');
    }
```

here is view students> **payments.blade.php**

```
@forelse ($student->payments as $key => $payment)
                            <tr class="center aligned">
                              <td>{{++$key}}</td>
                              <td>{{$payment->course_id}}</td>
                              <td>{{$payment->payment_type_id</td>
                              <td>{{$payment->transfer_amount}}</td>
                              <td>
                              @if($payment->is_paid)
                                 <p style="color: green;">Paid</p>

                              @else <p style="color: red">Not Paid</p>
                              @endif
                              </td>
                     @empty
                       <tr class="center aligned">
                       <td colspan="12" class="ui red header">No data</td>
                        </tr>
                     @endforelse
```

error Not unique table/alias showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update your query like:

```
public function payments($id, Request $request) {
       $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
       $payment = Student::with('payments')->where('id', $id)->get();

       return view('students.groups', compact('student', 'payment'));

   }
```

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE 5/5/2017**
I think you Should Update payments.blade.php

```
@forelse ($student->payments as $key => $payment)
    <tr class="center aligned">
        <td>{{++$key}}</td>
        <td>{{$payment->course_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$payment->payment_type_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$payment->transfer_amount}}</td>
        <td>
        @if($payment->is_paid)
            <p style="color: green;">Paid</p>

        @else <p style="color: red">Not Paid</p>
        @endif
    </td>
@empty
<tr class="center aligned">
    <td colspan="12" class="ui red header">No data</td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

Comment: no, it is not working giving the exact error @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have the variable `$payment`? Did you use this somewhere or anywhere in the view? If not, then this will probably the right eloquent syntax:

```
public function payments($id, Request $request) {
    $student = Student::with('payments')->where('student_id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('students.groups', compact('student'));
}
```

In the above example, it is searching for a user with id of `$id` and include its `payments` details using relationships that's defined in the model.

If you need to validate the student MUST always has at least 1 payment, then you could add `has('payments')` to the syntax like so:

```
public function payments($id, Request $request) {
    $student = Student::has('payments')->with('payments')->where('student_id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('students.groups', compact('student'));
}
```

This will return ONLY if the student has at least 1 payment stored in the database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah as you see I used '$student->payments as $key => $payment' in the view as counter

Comment: I guess you don't have to add `$payment` in the controller then, in the view, you're creating a new `$payment` variable ONLY for the loop, so it doesn't really need to be added in the controller's method